# Can't change node parameters outside of function call

Tags: c++, class

I am making a function that is trying to insert an int into a node into a tree. As far as I know, my insert function works perfectly but outside of the function, it's like it never happened. Here's my code:

lcrs.h:

```
using namespace std;
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

class node{
        public:
        int data;
        node *right;
        node *below;

        node()
        {
                right = NULL;
                below = NULL;
        }
};

class lcrs{
        public:
        node *root;
        bool search(int, node*);
        void print(node*);
        void insert(int, node*);
        int getHeight(node*);

        lcrs()
        {
                root = NULL;
        }
};
```

And lcrs.cpp:

```
using namespace std;
#include "lcrs.h"

bool lcrs::search(int x, node *b)
{
        if(b == NULL)
                return false;
        else
        {
                if(b->data == x)
                        return true;
                else
                {
                        return search(x, b->right) || search(x, b->below);
                }
        }
}

void lcrs::print(node *z)
{
        if(z->right == NULL && z->below == NULL)
        {
                cout << z->data << endl;
        }
        else if(z->below == NULL && z->right != NULL)
        {
                cout << z->data << ", ";
                print(z->right);
        }
        }
        else if(z->below != NULL && z->right == NULL)
        {
                cout << z->data << ", ";
                print(z->below);
        }
        else
        {
                print(z->right);
                print(z->below);
        }
}

void lcrs::insert(int x, node *a)
{
        if(a == NULL)
        {
                node *newnode;
                newnode = new node;
                newnode->data = x;
                a = newnode;
                cout << a->data << endl;
        }
        else if(a->data < x)
        {
                if(a->right != NULL)
                {
                        insert(x, a->right);
                }
                else
                        a->right->data = x;
        }
        else
        {
                if(a->below != NULL)
                {
                        insert(x, a->below);
                }
                else
                {
                        a->below->data = x;
                }
        }
}

int lcrs::getHeight(node *h)
{
        int height = 0;
        if(h->below != NULL)
        {
                height ++;
                return getHeight(h->below);
        }
        else
                return height;
}
```

And finally my main.cpp:

```
using namespace std;
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include "lcrs.h"

int main()
{
char *temp1;
char *temp2;
temp1 = new char;
temp2 = new char;

lcrs tree;

do{
        cout << "LCRS> ";
        cin >> temp1;
        if(strcmp(temp1, "quit") == 0)
        {
                return 0;
        }
        if(strcmp(temp1, "insert") == 0)
        {       cin >> temp2;
                bool error;
                for(int i=0; i<strlen(temp2)-1; i++)
                {
                        if(!isdigit(temp2[i]))
                        {
                                cout << "Error!" << endl;
                                error = true;
                        }
                }
                if(!error)
                {
                        tree.insert(atoi(temp2), tree.root);
                        if(tree.root == NULL)
                                cout << "Root is null." << endl;
                        else
                                cout << tree.root->data << endl;
                }
        }
        else if(strcmp(temp1, "height") == 0)
        {
                if(tree.root == NULL)
                        cout << "-1" << endl;
                else
                        cout << tree.getHeight(tree.root);
        }
        else if(strcmp(temp1, "preorder") == 0)
        {
                tree.print(tree.root);
        }
}while(strcmp(temp1, "quit") !=0);

return 0;
}
```

So I understand that my **insert** function isn't actually changing the **root** of **tree**, I just don't understand why.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Lookup pass be reference and pass by value - you are doing pass by value but you are wanting it to behave as pass by reference.

Answer (score 2):

Your code:

```
void lcrs::insert(int x, node *a)
{
        if(a == NULL)
        {
                node *newnode;
                newnode = new node;
                newnode->data = x;
                a = newnode;
```

↑ This assignment does not update the actual argument, because it was passed by value.

```
                cout << a->data << endl;
        }
        else if(a->data < x)
        {
                if(a->right != NULL)
                {
                        insert(x, a->right);
                }
                else
                        a->right->data = x;
```

↑ Here you know (have ensured) that `a->right` is a nullpointer. Dereferencing that nullpointer yields **Undefined Behavior**. For example a crash.

```
        }
        else
        {
                if(a->below != NULL)
                {
                        insert(x, a->below);
                }
                else
                {
                        a->below->data = x;
                }
```

↑ Here you know (have ensured) that `a->below` is a nullpointer. Dereferencing that nullpointer yields **Undefined Behavior**. For example a crash.
            }
    }

As a general comment, `below` and `right` mixes two metaphors. Better call them `below` and `above`, or `left` and `right`. The latter choice is very common.

Instead of passing the node pointer by reference (to fix the non-update problem), consider returning it as function result.

Comment: thank you! That helped a lot.
Also, The way the tree is set up is like an L, so **below** and **right** visually make sense.

Answer (score 1):

You're passing the pointer to a using pass by value; to get pass by reference you need to use `void lcrs::insert(int x, node * & a)` which passes a reference to `a` rather than `a` itself.  What happens is that the pointer to the node is copied into a local variable, referenced as `a` within the function.  Then the function is free to make changes to the copy (and even to the memory to which it points), but when the function returns, the caller has no idea what happened with the copy, as it's still looking at the original.

With pass by reference, the caller and the called function both use the same thing, rather than one using a copy and the other using the original.